# Set a default value in an ion-datetime Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I want to make an edit form and I need to set a default date in the ion-datetime.

**The .html**

```
<ion-datetime #fecha displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myVar" pickerFormat="DD MM YYYY" doneText="Ok" cancelText="Cancelar"></ion-datetime>
```

**The .ts**

```
public myVar = "15-06-1999";
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
myDate: String = new Date(yourdate).toISOString();
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, h:mm A" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
```